# BrickBreaker .Gameplay is not abstract and does not override error

Tags: java, abstract-class, actionlistener

My error code is:

```
BrickBreaker .Gameplay is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPreformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent) in java.awt.event.ActionListener
```

Here is my Gameplay Class. (It is incomplete because i am still working on it. and using this "simple game" to try and learn Java better.

```
package BrickBreaker;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.Timer;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

**public class Gameplay extends JPanel implements KeyListener, ActionListener {
    private boolean play = false;
    private int score = 0;

    private int totalBreaks = 21;

    private Timer time;
    private int delay = 8;

    private int playerX = 310;
    private int ballposX = 120;
    private int ballposY = 350;
    private int ballXdir = -1;
    private int ballYdir = -2;


    **@Override
    public void actionPreformed(ActionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }

}
```

I have an error on the Highlighted lines with the two asterisk, any sort of help is appreciated.

Comment: A simple typo! Instead of `actionPerformed`, you wrote `actionPreformed`

Comment: @CoderCharmander thank you. i looked at my spelling 1000 times too.